# Android: Custom Dialog Calculator laying out different on Android 2.2.1 and 2.3.3

Tags: android, xml, layout, dialog, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've created a custom dialog that is a simple calculator.  I'm having a problem with the layout in Android 2.3.3.  The dialog wraps the calculator perfect in 2.2.1 and lower, but in 2.3.3 it doesn't.  Below I've posted picture of that is happening and the XML code for the layout.  And below that is the code on how i start the Dialog. Thanks for all the help!!!

[image: dialog on HTC thunderbold 2.2.1]

[image: dialog on droidX 2.3.3]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/calc_dialog_display"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size" 
        android:editable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="right"     
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/calc_dialog_display_fake"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:editable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="right"     
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter_total"
        android:text="@string/calc_dialog_enter_total_button"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/calc_dialog_display"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/all_clear"
        android:text="AC"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/all_clear_color"
        android:layout_below="@id/calc_dialog_display"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/enter_total"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/enter_total"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/enter_total"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/seven"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/enter_total"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/eight"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/division"
        android:text="÷"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/enter_total"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nine"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/seven"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/seven"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/four"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/seven"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/five"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multiply"
        android:text="x"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/seven"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/six"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/four"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/four"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/four"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/two"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subtract"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/four"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/three"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decimal"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/one"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/one"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/decimal"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/equals"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/one"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/zero"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addition"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="@dimen/calc_dialog_text_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/one"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/equals"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/calc_dialog_button_height" />     
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    super.onCreateDialog(id);
    Dialog dialog = null;

    switch(id){
    case 1:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this, shippingPercent, QUICK_CALC_TRIGGER);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Shipping %");
        break;
    case 2:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this, taxPercent, QUICK_CALC_TRIGGER);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Tax Rate");
        break;
    case 3:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this, commissionPercent, QUICK_CALC_TRIGGER);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Commission %");
        break;
    case 4:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this, productSubtotal, QUICK_CALC_TRIGGER);
        dialog.setTitle("Calculate Subtotal");
        break;
    case 5:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this, addShipping, QUICK_CALC_TRIGGER);
        dialog.setTitle("Additional Shipping");
        break;
    case 6:
        dialog = new BackgroundOptionsDialog(this, quickCalcBackground);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose Background:");
        break;
    case 7:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this, shippingDollar, QUICK_CALC_TRIGGER);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Shipping $");
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: is that Calculate Subtotal the Dialog Header? can you post how are you creating yor dialog... and why do you have Two Relative layouts... although it should not make any difference.

Comment: I just updated the my post on how i create the dialog.  Yes the Calculate Subtotal is the Header.  Depending on what the user clicks on to start a Dialog the header changes.  I don't have a good reason to have two Relative layouts.  I will take one out to see what happens.

Comment: @Necronet... i took out the extra Relative layout and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I found a fix.  inserted the below code in the onCreate() for the Custom Dialog.

```
Window windowProperties = getWindow();
windowProperties.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Setting the setBackgroundDrawable() to null makes it so the background is opaque.  This fixed the problem and it still work in lower versions of Android.

[image: The Fixed Picture]

Thanks for all the suggestionos

Answer (score 0):

try setting the relativelayout's width to fill_parent

Comment: I changed the relativelayouts width to fill and it got a little more screwy.  http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/3525/droidxwidthfill233.png This is a link to the pick of what is happening with the width to fill_parent.

Comment: take out the upper relativelayout, then set the remaining relativelayout's layout_gravity to center_horizontal

Comment: That didn't make a difference.  Still looks just like this with those changes http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/3525/droidxwidthfill233.png